# In a constructor, set the constructed object to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

To help in my logging, I created a convenience function that create a `winston.Logger` and set it with the correct transports, and return that logger.

Everything works fine, but ESLint is complaining I am calling what it see as a constructor without using `new`.

While I could just ignore the warning, I like to have strict rules, and seeing `const logger = Logger('foo')` is indeed confusing.

Renaming `Logger` to something like `getLogger` seems ugly to me, but ESLint don't complain.

What I thought was to make `Logger` a constructor, that directly point to the result of `new winston.Logger`.

Obviously, `this = new winston.Logger` didn't worked, but I am pretty sure there is a clean way to do this.

Current snippet of `log.js`:

```
module.exports = (file) => {
    let transports = getTransports(file),
        logger = new (winston.Logger)({
            rewriters: [
                (level, msg, meta) => {
                    meta.app = file + '.js';
                    return meta;
                }
            ],
            transports: transports
        });
    return logger;
    // this = logger;
};
```

Use:

```
'use strict';

const Logger = require('./log.js'),
    logger = Logger('foo');

logger.debug('foo');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, the warning is there because functions with initially-capped names are normally constructor functions in JavaScript.

If you want, you can call your existing `Logger` with `new`. That will create and throw away an object, but that's harmless. It works because if a constructor function returns a non-`null` object reference, the result of `new` is that object reference instead of the object created by `new`. Your function returns `logger`, which is a non-`null` object reference, so it'll work. (If it were me, I'd probably call it `getLogger` and just call it normally, to make it clear what it's doing, but that's a matter of style and you've said you don't want to, which is fair enough.)

Here's a simpler example to demonstrate this behavior of `new` and constructor functions:

```js
var obj = {
  note: "I'm the one object Singleton always returns"
};
function Singleton() {
  this.note = "This object is thrown away, so you never see this object";
  return obj;
}
function Normal() {
  this.note = "This object isn't thrown away";
}

var o1 = Singleton();
console.log("o1", o1);
var o2 = new Singleton();
console.log("o1 === o2? ",  o1 === o2);  // true
console.log("o1 === obj?", o1 === obj); // true
var n1 = new Normal();
console.log("n1", n1);
var n2 = new Normal();
console.log("n1 === n2?", n1 === n2);   // false
```

Comment: Thanks, it also limit the modification I have to do in the codebase. :) As for the style, I ll see what my team have to say about it in code review, but since it is not hackish, and they too dislike importing a unique function with `require`, that solution is perfect.